# Symfony 3.4.4 + MariaDB 10.0.1 - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: debian, mariadb, symfony-3.4

I have a new VPS server (Debian), with the basic things installed

I have installed a symfony project that I have in place in local environment and it works perfectly.

When executing the database creation command:
`bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`" 
I get the following error:

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 115:

An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE salepoint (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, slug VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_56CEF7DA989D9B62 (slug), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':  

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes                                                                                                                                                                          


In PDOConnection.php line 106:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes  


In PDOConnection.php line 104:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

As you can see in this link https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14904, it seems to be a bug of MariaDB 10.0

I tried to update it to version 10.1 using this documentation:
https://websiteforstudents.com/install-upgrade-to-mariadb-10-1-10-2-10-3-latest-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-server/

Executing:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Get this message:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   software-properties-common is already the newest version.
>   You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.1 (= 10.1.32+maria-1~jessie) but it is not going to be installed
>    mariadb-server-10.0 : Depends: mariadb-client-10.0 (>= 10.0.32-0+deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
>                          Depends: mariadb-server-core-10.0 (>= 10.0.32-0+deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Executing next step:

```
apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client
```

Get this message:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   mariadb-server is already the newest version.
>   You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    mariadb-client : Depends: mariadb-client-10.1 (= 10.1.32+maria-1~jessie) but it is not going to be installed
>    mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.1 (= 10.1.32+maria-1~jessie) but it is not going to be installed
>    mariadb-server-10.0 : Depends: mariadb-client-10.0 (>= 10.0.32-0+deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
>                          Depends: mariadb-server-core-10.0 (>= 10.0.32-0+deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

5 solutions are available [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes) ; pick the one you prefer.